# On what basis do some countries oppose President Assad?

Tags: syria

**TL;DR:** on what basis do some (mostly western) countries condemn the democratically elected Assad?

---

In my understanding, President Assad was **democratically elected**. He has won elections 3 times:

- In [2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_presidential_election,_2000) he was the only candidate to run to replace his father
- In [2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_presidential_election,_2007) there was a referendum asking the people whether he should continue serving as president
- In [2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_presidential_election,_2014) there was a difficult to administrate election during the civil war, but he won 88.7% of the vote with 73.42% turnout

---

Of course it is open to question whether the elections were truly democratic:

> Long before the conflict began, many Syrians complained about high
>   unemployment, widespread corruption, a lack of political freedom and
>   state repression under President Bashar al-Assad, who succeeded his
>   father, Hafez, in 2000.

Comment: This's really quite broad to be answered, but you can check out [this article by BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/10338256) which summarises some of the reasons. Also, in the Wikipedia articles you listed: `Political opposition groups were banned unless attached to the Ba'ath Party, meaning Assad was the only candidate allowed to run.`. Doesn't this defeat the purpose of having democratic elections? Which is also why western countries doesn't regard it as democratic.

Comment: Similar: [Why don't Western powers support Bashar al-Assad once it became clear most of the opposition is not in support of democratic government?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16934/why-dont-western-powers-support-bashar-al-assad-once-it-became-clear-most-of-th) and [Why is US supporting ISIS in Syria while opposing it in Iraq?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/why-is-us-supporting-isis-in-syria-while-opposing-it-in-iraq)

Comment: Obligatory *reductio ad Hitlerum* argument: Adolf Hitler has also been democratically elected.

Comment: @bytebuster - far more democratically, actually.

Comment: "democratically elected" and, as example "he was the only candidate" lol

Comment: daily reminder that democratic states do not posses a better track record than the totalitarian, and, in fact, the so called "totalitarian" state may in fact better protect the rights of it's citizenry in a threatening world.

Comment: @easymoden00b : Why would you need a daily remimder than reminds you of something false ?